# Action sheet to other interfaces/devices

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I was doing an action sheet in order to pop up 3 options, take a photo, choose a photo or  cancel . The app initialy was for ipad only, but now I'm implementing it on iphone. The problem seems to be in the Interface, because it is set on ipad.
Here is the code:

```
#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate methods

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{   
    CustomImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[CustomImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];

    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    } else if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    }

    CGSize winsize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20,20,10,10);
    rect.origin = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:rect.origin];

    _popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [_popoverController setDelegate:self];
    [_popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(winsize.width, winsize.height) animated:NO];
    [_popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

Here is the error:

```
2013-02-27 15:35:31.437 xxxxxxxx [8492:707] cocos2d: surface size: 480x320
2013-02-27 15:35:32.848 xxxxxxxx [8492:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'
```

How can I set this action sheet to both devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `UIPopoverViewController` on iPhone or iPod Touch, it's a class that is only to be instantiated on iPad.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't knew it. What could I do or use?

Comment: @Vergmort Your iPad, if you want this class :)

Comment: @Vergmort But seriously, why didn't you know that? [Haven't you read the documentation of this class?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009306-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) "Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception."